# Converting Numbers into Words

Tags: javascript, numbers, number-formatting

I have taken this code from Stackoverflow and modified it, but i am unable to convert number for more than 3 digits.

Here is the code:

```
var num = this.rawValue;
var a = ['','one ','two ','three ','four ', 'five ','six ','seven ','eight ','nine ','ten ','eleven ','twelve ', 'thirteen  ','fourteen ','fifteen ','sixteen ','seventeen ','eighteen ','nineteen '];
var b = ['', '', 'twenty','thirty','forty','fifty', 'sixty','seventy','eighty','ninety'];
var c = ['thousand', 'million', ''];

num = num.toString();

num = ( '000000000' + num ).substr( -9 ); // // Make number into a predictiable nine character string
num = num.match( /.{3}/g ); // Split string into chuncks of three numbers then reverse order of returned array

var words = '';

for( var i = 0; i < c.length; i++ ) {

    var n = num[i];
    var str = '';
    str += ( words != '' ) ? ' ' + c[i] + ' ' : '';
    str += ( n[0] != 0 ) ? ( a[Number( n[0] )] + 'hundred ' ) : '';
    n = n.substr( 1 );
    str += ( n != 0 ) ? ( ( str != '' ) ? 'and ' : '' ) + ( a[Number( n )] || b[n[0]] + ' ' + a[n[1]] ) : '';
    words += str;

}

data.Text.TextField1.rawValue= words;
```

I want to convert number into words for more than 3 digits and to also consider decimal values.

The current code converts up to thousand and it interprets values before decimal point as undefined. The above code was used in javascript under adobe form (sap).

Answer (score 0):

In the `for` loop replace `c[i]` by `c[c.length-1-i]`. This works for me. I just found out that the index specified for the Array `c` gave wrong results because it kinda went from the wrong direction.

I’m sure this could be optimized in other ways as well.

[JSFiddle for testing and experimenting](http://jsfiddle.net/uy77rnsb/2/).

Comment: Thanks for the effort Xufox. I edited the above code to get the words in south Asian format.

Comment: Hey @sanny, if this answer finally solved your problem consider marking it as _accepted_ so that the community can better see whether this solution worked or not. If not, please let us know.